# ChilliCream graphql: using variables to define order_by

Tags: sorting, dynamic, graphql, hotchocolate

I have a working graphql query:

```
query orderOnTheFly {
  products(order:{ id: ASC, status: ASC }) 
  {
    nodes { id status }
  }
}
```

Now I have to implement (on frontend) the user selects which field ( `id` or `status`) and which order (`ASC` or `DESC`) wants to use (ordering by only one field at a time). What I wanted to write (for example $fieldName="id", $order="ASC" - to let ordering `id ASC`):

```
query orderOnTheFly( $fieldName:String, $order:String) {
  products(order:{ $fieldName: $order }) 
  {
    nodes { id status }
  }
}
```

or at least ($idOrder=null, $statusOrder="ASC" - when I do not select `id` field into ordering, only by `status ASC`)

```
query orderOnTheFly( $idOrder:String, $statusOrder:String) {
  products(order:{ id: $idOrder, status: $statusOrder }) 
  {
    nodes { id status }
  }
}
```

Neither of them work. How to solve this situation?

The frontend uses react-relay compiler, so I don't want to generate the graphql query with string manipulation. Otherwise - my graphql server is a .net core server with hotChocolate package (and the database is a Marten event store).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to avoid generating the query using string manipulation is to write your query to use a `variables` object for the input. react-relay can "compile" the query and then the `variables` object can be defined at runtime.

Comment: But to do that some server side changes are needed as far as I understand... currently the ASC and DESC are the ones that are allowed here. Do I understand you well?

Comment: Yes, correct. The server would need to strip any key ordered by "NONE" from the sort.

Comment: But - as far as I see the graphql wont accept variable names there, so this still not enough I think :(

Comment: [Variables](https://relay.dev/docs/guided-tour/rendering/variables/) are a standard part of GraphQL. Your query defines variable names such as `idOrder` and `statusOrder`. These are the variables that you need to provide to the query.